# Genymotion VS real device

Tags: android-studio, genymotion

Which one is better for emulations? Or more reliably?

I was using an s4 mini for app testing but recently I bought a Huawei gr3 and can't set it to an android studio so I'm really looking forward to using genymotion.

Comment: didi you download gennymotion. what you want to knw about that

Comment: Yes. I have it and have used it. And also have used a real device but I heard that using a real device for debugging is better

Comment: if you have an efficient ram in your system there is no problem for using genny motion . otherwise please use your mobile . the  main use of genny motion is that that we can check the app in different type of devices

Answer (score 0):

Using an actual mobile phone is always going to be preferred over using an emulator. Emulation of Android systems is mostly used when developers are trying to minimize the risk of their applications not running the way they intended them to run on devices they don't have physical copies of. Get your application working well on a mobile device first, then use an emulator to ensure that your application runs well on other types of devices.